# Questions and Answers as Downloads

Tags: feature-request

I don't know if Physics.SE or other SE sites have this feature.

If they don't, I suggest a new feature. Can we have the questions and answers available as downloads. We can simply save the html file but it's tiresome when one wants to download too many questions. Can we have a topic-wise(or should I say tag-wise) collection of different questions? It maybe be a great help to students and teachers as it can show the wide range of questions which can arise out of a topic and it can also address some common misconceptions.

We can have it like a separate set of files for questions related to a particular phenomenon. For, example all questions related to Hawking Radiation available as download.

**EDIT**: For example, [this](http://www.stackprinter.com/deleted) page is an archive of deleted popular questions.

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/3307/print-this-post

Comment: @Manishearth Chrome doesn't allow me to add the app. And btw, that's nearly the same as saving the whole page as a file.

Comment: There's a link right there in the installation instructions "see this link if you have trouble". Use it, it has the workaround for Chrome among other things. And no, it isn't the same, it only gets the post text. All the superfluous things like the header and sidebar and all are ignored.

Comment: This should be asked in: http://www.meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: Should I paste it there too or do I have to delete this one first?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking for, but this is indeed available on a site-wide scale. This is done via the

## [Stack Exchange Data Dump.](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange)

This is a collection of all the questions and answers in each Stack Exchange site, which is updated on every ~3 months if I remember correctly. This is publicly available to download, and its use is governed by the same [CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license that governs Stack Exchange user contributions. For more information see [this SE blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/), [this one](http://blog.stackexchange.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/) on the migration to the Internet Archive, and of course [the mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede).

While I'm at this, I should note that this database can be accessed directly by anyone with SQL skills at the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) ([description in the mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/stack-exchange-data-explorer)), which is a goldmine for site usage statistics among other things.

Again, I'm not sure exactly what the OP is asking for, but this is mostly a reply to the question title, meant for people that are looking for exactly that.

Comment: I downloaded one from Stack Exchange Dump but it was all just code.

Comment: Yes, it is a complicated data set, and it is meant for pretty intensive use. The database schema, which you can use to make sense of how the data stored is in [the mother meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede). If by "just code" you mean it does not have any html formatting, then that is of course correct - it's meant to have the minimum amount of essential information about the posts, and not bloated by unnecessary formatting.

Comment: But what I am talking of is that the questions posted on each site along with the answers and comments be available as classified downloads. By classified I mean the questions be divided according the tags and the level. And not just as code but as actual pages as they appear here.

Comment: So what's wrong with a save-as-pdf app? What's your use scenario, anyway? Just print out all the [tag:quantum-mechanics] questions to use in a classroom?

Comment: Does such an app exist? And maybe not all questions under a particular tag. Like under GR, you have questions about cosmological constant, curvature of space-time, twin paradox etc.

Comment: Well, it obviously depends on what browser you're using, but I would start [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=save+webpage+as+pdf).

Comment: Yes. That is useful. But I will have to classify them myself. I am talking about a classified single pdf per topic.

Comment: Yes, but what is a "topic"? A single tag? (potentially thousands of questions). A single search? How can you algorithmically define this, in a way that will be useful for more than a couple of people?

Comment: I should also note that the best way to get Stack Exchange interested in adding a new feature to the network is to have a working prototype. You can build one using the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) and whatever outside tools can be accessed programatically. If you can define a "topic" in a way that will play well with the API (which is what you need to play well with the database of posts!) then the API search will give you a list of post IDs, and you can use that to feed your save-as-pdf app the URLs using fairly simple javascript.

Comment: I am a very basic programmer and I don't know Javascript. Is there someone on StackExchange to whom I may officially request?

Comment: If you look at it as an 'official request' then you're going to have a hard time. Try, instead, to convince someone that this is a worthwhile thing to implement. (But again, you should have a clearly defined concept, which you don't yet, for this to be a feasible project.) Meta.StackExchange and StackApps are the places to go with this.

Comment: There's also [SO2PDF](http://stackapps.com/questions/1559/so2pdf-export-questions-and-answers-to-pdf) at StackApps, but I'm not sure it's still working. Try contacting the authors - in a respectful manner, obviously.

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess, but this would probably defeat the purpose of this site, which is to provide eyeballs to view ads.

At best a download would include the ads you would have seen at that time.  However, there is no way to track new views, and the ads could go stale.  In the case of rotating ads, whichever one you got with your snapshot would get all the future views and the other paying advertisers would get none.  You'd also not see the results of new voting, new answers, or other updates to the page.

SE needs you to come back to the live site whenever you want to look at some question or answer again.

Comment: But still SE is still one of the sites with the least ads and when a user downloads the set of files. One could automatically assume that they have seen the ads.